# JavaScript Auto suggest to update multiple fields

Tags: javascript, ajax, autosuggest

I have a simple autocomplete field that spits out a bunch of suggested words and puts it in the suggest field. Is there an auto suggest code that can enter the selected text but also auto fill a range of other fields instead of the selected field?

For example, searching through a contacts list you type their name or address and it suggests options. On clicking one it automatically draws from the database the rest of the available contact details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ought to be able to do this with the [Autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) plugin.   Add a [result handler](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/result#handler) and use it to populate your other fields.

```
 $('div#result').result( function(e,data,formatted) {
      $(this).html(formatted);
      $('div#address').html(data.address);
      ...
 });
```

Comment: Looks like the demos give examples of doing just this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Ajax.Autocompleter](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/ajax-autocompleter) from script.aculo.us, you can override the afterUpdateElement function to do this for you.  You could then make a call that could send back JSON like the following:

```
{ fields: ['first', 'second'],
  first: 'value',
  second: 'another value' }
```

and populate your form with something like:

```
for(field in json.fields)
  $(field).value = json.getAttribute(field);
```